# How to prove there exists a unique "zero-contour" for a non-monotone function?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, analysis, multivariable-calculus, polynomials

Let $$z = \frac{8xy+x+y}{4x+4y+2},$$ where $0<x<y<1$.

We have the following function of interest:
$$f(u) = \frac{1-\phi}{\sqrt{u}}-\frac{\phi}{1-\sqrt{u}}, 
\quad  0<\phi<\frac{1}{4}.$$

**I want to prove that:**

For any given $0<\phi<1/4$, there exists a unique and monotone zero-curve for $f(x) + f(y) - 2f(z)$. Namely:
there exists a threshold function $F()$ such that:
$f(x) + f(y) - 2f(z) < 0$ iff $x>F(y)$, and $F(y)$ decreases in $y$.

I have numerically verified the above hypothesis.

Numerical study also shows that  $f(x)+f(y)-2f(z)$ is not monotone in $(x,y)$, so monotonicity does not work here. Is there any other way to show the uniqueness of the monotonicity of the zero contour? Thank you very much for your help!

[image: Numerical Verification]